# Hi i have a custom visual force page , in this i was unable to use onchange event

Tags: apex, visualforce

My VF Page has Account Lookup and salesDistrict lookup ,when user chnage the account  value i have to populate the accout's sales value in sales lookup field. Folowing is my code

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText=" The End User’s physical location" >
Account Name:
<apex:inputField id="oppAccountId" value="{!thisOpp.AccountId}" required="true">
<apex:actionSupport action="{!populatesalesdistrict}" event="onchange" reRender="salesDistrict" status="pageStatus"/> </apex:inputField>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="Auto populated from Account; Enter if blank">
Sales District :
<apex:inputField value="{!thisOpp.Sales_District_lkup__c}" id="salesDistrict" required="true"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

controller: Mrthod:

```
  Public void populatesalesdistrict(){
       Account thisAcc = [SELECT Id, Sales_District__c,SoldTo__c from Account where ID =: thisOpp.AccountId];
       thisOpp.Sales_District_lkup__c = thisAcc.Sales_District__c;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "required" attribute causes pre-action validation to occur; if the field is not already populated, you'll get a required field error. You'll need to put the one lookup field inside an action region:

```
<apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="false">
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText=" The End User’s physical location" >
Account Name:
<apex:inputField id="oppAccountId" value="{!thisOpp.AccountId}" required="true">
<apex:actionSupport action="{!populatesalesdistrict}" event="onchange" reRender="salesDistrict" status="pageStatus"/> </apex:inputField>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

This should give you the behavior you're looking for. Some additional changes may be necessary to fix styling problems.